# Picklist value translation

Tags: apex, picklist, translation

I have am email body I'm generating in APEX and I want it to include the translated value of a picklist.
How can I get the translated value in APEX?

Answer (score 10):

You can use a SOQL function `toLabel()` to get translated picklist values:

```
SELECT toLabel(your_field__c) FROM YourObject__c
```

[Here is the official documentation:](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm)

> A client application can have results from a query returned that are
>   translated into the user’s language, using toLabel()

Comment: mind adding a documentation reference or explaining how this function works ?

Comment: thanx @mast0r for adding the documentation link and for the edit :)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not ideal for me, I have the records already (getting them from the trigger). I prefer not to query again.  I hoped there is something like 'getTranslatedValue()' or something like quering the translated values themselves

Comment: How about using email templates ? then you don't need to worry about translations SForce does it for you